# firebase auth: TypeError: (0, _reactNative.getReactNativePersistence) is not a function. react-native EXPO

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I use **expo** for **react-native** and want to initialize **firebase auth** in my react-native app.
There is the following error to fix:

```
TypeError: (0, _reactNative.getReactNativePersistence) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNative.getReactNativePersistence)(_asyncStorage.default)', '(0, _reactNative.getReactNativePersistence)' is undefined)
```

My **firebase init file** is the following:

```
import { initializeApp, FirebaseApp, getApps, getApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { Auth, getAuth, initializeAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth/react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";


// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
...app
};

let app;
let auth;
if (getApps().length < 1) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
  });
} else {
  app = getApp();
  auth = getAuth();
}

const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
});
const storage = getStorage(app);
export {db, auth, storage};
```

Here is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "~15.4.0",
    "@react-native-segmented-control/segmented-control": "^2.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~6.4.0",
    "firebase": "^9.1.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-expo-cached-image": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am using Firebase 9.1 because the [documentation of EXPO](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/) recommend to do so. The reason why I use the _reactNative.getReactNativePersistence is to prevent the warning:

```
Firebase on React Native should import AsyncStorage from @react-native-community/async-storage
```

As a reference you find here the issue to the warning:
[Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1847)

[image: error]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the `package.json` as text or a clear screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The `getReactNativePersistence()` was added in Firebase [`v9.4.1`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_941_-_november_11_2021). Your `package.json` isn't clearly readable but that seems to be `9.1.0`. Try updating to latest version using `npm i firebase@latest`.

Comment: When I am using the latest firebase version. I am getting an error (Unable to resolve "idb" from "node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js"). Expo recommend firebase version 9.1.

Comment: @tk97tk have you tried installing `firebase@9.6.11`? That seems to be working in some cases.